# Location province views exposed filter as a select list or checkboxes?

Tags: 7, views, location

I'm displaying google map using gmap and location module through views.

I want to add a province exposed filter to the view as a select list or checkboxes but I'm unable to do this.

When I add the province filter, it displays as a simple textfield.

Any option or some kind of small code to accomplish this functionality.

I also tried better exposed filter but nothing change.

Comment: I think there's a patch to get provinces as a select list

Comment: Whats the link of that patch please?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/364287 this should be it, was an issue with the Ajax

Comment: that issue is also for a content type or profile. It does not contain any solution for the views exposed filter.

Comment: I thought they would be related, sounded like Ajax issue